# Upgrading Xcode on Mac OS X Leopard?

Tags: macos, upgrade, osx-leopard, xcode

All of the Xcode upgrades I can find are Snow Leopard only.  Can you still upgrade Xcode on Leopard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install xcode 3.1 which is on your leopard install disk, or can be found by visiting http://developer.apple.com/ registering as a developer (it's free) going to "downloads" then "developer tools (in the right column)" XCode 3.1.4 is about half way down.

Xcode 3.2+ can only be installed on Snow Leopard.